# Vincular Def a un Boton, Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen día, Estoy buscado la forma de vincular este pequeño codigo complementandolo a un def para poder usarlo mediante un Botón.

El código lo que hace es darme del 1 al 10, con cada **Ente** me da el numero **+1**, llegando así hasta 10.

Ejemplo: Con el primer **Enter** da el numero **1**, Con el segundo **Enter** da el numero **2** y asi consecutivamente

Lo que busco es ponerlo en un **def** y usar a función con un botón. El boton lo unico que hace es comenzar la el **def** pero para imprimir los numeros de 1 en uno, aun es con **Enter** por el input(), Pero si saco el input() Me imprimirá todo los números de una.

Lo que busco esque el boton reemplace la funcion del input, De esa forma cada vez que se dea click en el boton pase al siguiente numero.

Este es el código:

```
ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")

def pri():
   for i in range(1,10+1):
      foo = input()
      print(i)
      i = i+1

boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Compila pls",command=pri, width="30", height="2", bg="#00CD63")
boton.place(x=22, y=320)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok, indicas que el botón corre tu función, pero no indicas qué quiere que haga, que el botón "reemplace" al `input()` ? Osea que pase al siguiente número cada que le haces click?

Comment: @DannyTalent Exactamente, El boton pase al siguiente numero al darle click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **En tu función `pri()`:**

La forma en la que lo hiciste no puede darse, dado que es una especie de *hack* hacer que Python espere una entrada de teclado para evitar que continúe un loop. Mejor, declaras la variable `i = 1` y luego llamas tu función cada vez que quieras imprimir la variable y añadirle 1. Cuando llega a 10, se resetea `i = 1`.

```
def pri():
    global i
    if i > 10:
        i = 1
    print(i)
    i+=1
i = 1
```

El uso de `global` es para "jalar" la variable `i` de otro *contexto* (desde afuera de la función), porque normalmente la función no tiene idea de qué variables se usan externamente (a menos que las pases como argumentos).

Luego puedes añadir el código de tu GUI y debería funcionar como esperas.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono perfectamente!!

Comment: Disculpa una duda, Al llegar al numero 10, Se da un click que da nada, Y luego al siguiente click se repite el ciclo volviendo al numero 1. Es posible que del 10 pase al 1 ?

Comment: Cierto, se me pasó ese caso, le hice una pequeña modificación

Comment: Muchas Gracias!